# installing docker error on debian 8

Tags: docker, debian

when I want to  install docker I get this

```
N: Ignoring file 'backports.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listyy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'backports.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listyy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Package 'docker.io' has no installation candidate
N: Ignoring file 'backports.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listyy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'backports.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listyy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Package 'docker.io' has no installation candidate
N: Ignoring file 'backports.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listyy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'backports.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listyy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Package 'docker.io' has no installation candidate
N: Ignoring file 'backports.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listyy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'backports.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listyy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Package 'docker.io' has no installation candidate
N: Ignoring file 'backports.listy' in directory     '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listyy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'backports.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listyy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Package 'docker.io' has no installation candidate
N: Ignoring file 'backports.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listyy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'backports.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listyy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.listy' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Package 'docker.io' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 0):

First you've got the following files in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` with an file extension mix of either `.listy` or `.listyy`. Both are invalid, they should be `.list` or the files shouldn't be in there.

- `backports.listy`
- `docker.listyy`
- `docker.listy`
- `backports.listy`
- `docker.listyy`
- `docker.listy`

Where did those come from in the first place, did you do a tutorial or something? And could you provide the content, so i can get a guess why you would have them. Since it seems you want to get docker from a specific repository, hence their names.

The second error is `E: Package 'docker.io' has no installation candidate`, which wants to tell you that your package manager doesn't know this package. If you have repositorys configured do an `apt-get update`. You should then be able to get docker from those.

Also, next time please format your text and give us some more specific information. For example *'what command did you actually run?'* and *'what have you done before, regarding your task?* (i.e. creating listyy files and such)'

Comment: thank you  for the answer, IIremoved these files
    backports.listy
    docker.listyy
    docker.listy
    backports.listy
    docker.listyy
    docker.listy
 but now i gt this error  E: Package 'docker.io' has no installation candidate   and i want to install iodine with the docker

Comment: @user6269492 Did you execute `apt-get update` after that and it visibly updated the apt cache? Also if you enter `apt-get install docker` and press tabulator twice, does it suggest to you `docker.io`?